# Django: get users' IDs with field

Tags: python, django, models

I have a model, for example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = 
    surname = 
    city = 
    cars =
```

I need to get a list of the IDs (primary key auto-set) of the 5 users with the highest number of "cars" with a specific name.

I thought I could do something like:

```
    list = Person.objects.filter(name=name,)('-reputation')[5].id
```

Comment: Is `cars` a foreign key? When you say "with a specific name" are you talking about users with a specific name or cars with a specific name? See [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for how to get a list of ids from a queryset

Comment: It's not a foreign key; I've written "reputation" instead of "cars" in my example, but answers are fine for my purpose. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of the 5 users with the highest number you can use:

```
list = Person.objects.filter(name=name).order_by('-reputation')[:5]
```

to get the ID of each you can use for loop:

```
for user in list:
    userID = user.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed out the call to `order_by`.

```
Person.objects.filter(name=name).order_by('-reputation')[5].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`values_list` queryset function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) can reduce this to a single simple line:

```
Person.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).filter(name=name).order_by('-reputation')[:5]
```

and will avoid needing to loop.